# Polya Enumeration

Tags: abstract-algebra, dihedral-groups, polya-counting-theory

I have a circle divided into 60 pieces, and I have 4 different colors $(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)$, and I want to know how many different "colorings" I can get.

So I thought I would use the Polya Enumeration theorem, and I want to find the coefficient of the term in the polynomial with $c_1^{15} c_2^{15} c_3^{15} c_4^{15} $.

For this I looked at the Dihedral Group $D_{60}$, which is generated by $<\tau,\sigma >$, where $\sigma=(1\ 2\ \ldots \ 60)$ and $\tau=(1\ \ 60)(2\ \ 59)\ldots (30\ \ 31)$(a reflection). I already found all the $\sigma^i\ , \forall i=1,\ldots,60$, I mean their representation in cycles, but I still have to find at least $\tau \sigma = ?$ and I believe maybe also $\tau^2\sigma$ and others maybe.
After that and with the information I now have I would have to calculate the polynom $P(x_1,\ldots,x_{60})=\frac{1}{|D_{60}|}(x_1^{60}+x_{60}^j+\ldots)$.
So where I would need help is that I don't know exactly which combinations of $\tau^i\sigma^j$ I have to compose. And even better, if there is an easier solution for this, because the process of calculating all the $\sigma^i$ is not short, and I would still have to compute a massive Polynom...

I believe now that I have to see the cyclic structure of $\tau \sigma^i$, and not $\tau^j\sigma^i$. But still, if someone has a shorter method I would be very happy!

Comment: Do you mean to use each colour 15 times? If so please say so.

Comment: Yes, there are 60 pieces, so 15 pieces must have the same colour, so at the end I will look in the Polynom for the coefficient $A$ as in $Ac_1^{15}c_2^{15}c_3^{15}c_4^{15}$

Comment: But there are colourings with eg 3 Red 5 Blue 6 Green 46 Purple! So is the question "Find all colourings" or "Find all colourings using each colour 15 times"?

Comment: Find all colourings using each colour 15 times

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that part in the problem description

Answer (score 3):

To solve this by PET we  require the cycle index $Z(D_{60})$ (dihedral
group). We have the cycle index of the cyclic group:

$$Z(C_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) a_d^{n/d}.$$

Continuing we have the cycle index of the dihedral group

$$Z(D_n) =
\frac{1}{2} Z(C_n) +
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} a_1 a_2^{(n-1)/2} & n \text{ odd} \\
\frac{1}{4} \left( a_1^2 a_2^{n/2-1} + a_2^{n/2} \right)
& n \text{ even.}
\end{cases}$$

In the present case we find

$$Z(D_{60}) = 
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{60}}{120}}+1/4\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{29}
+{\frac {31\,{a_{{2}}}^{30}}{120}}+{\frac {{a_{{3}}}^{20}}{60}}
+{\frac {{a_{{4}}}^{15}}{60}}+1/30\,{a_{{5}}}^{12}
+{\frac {{a_{{6}}}^{10}}{60}}+1/30\,{a_{{10}}}^{6}
\\+1/30\,{a_{{12}}}^{5}+1/15\,{a_{{15}}}^{4}
+1/15\,{a_{{20}}}^{3}+1/15\,{a_{{30}}}^{2}+2/15\,a_{{60}}.$$

Working through these term by term and skipping the ones
that do not contribute leaves just

- $\frac{a_1^{60}}{120} :[C_1^{15} C_2^{15} C_3^{15} C_4^{15}]
  \frac{1}{120} (C_1 +  C_2 +  C_3 + C_4)^{60}
  \\ = \frac{1}{120} {60\choose 15,15,15,15} =
  23713472717216429668046154478080$
- $\frac{a_3^{20}}{60} :[C_1^{15} C_2^{15} C_3^{15} C_4^{15}]
  \frac{1}{60} (C_1^3 +  C_2^3 +  C_3^3 + C_4^3)^{20}
  \\ = [C_1^{5} C_2^{5} C_3^{5} C_4^{5}]
  \frac{1}{60} (C_1 +  C_2 +  C_3 + C_4)^{20}
  \\ = \frac{1}{60} {20\choose 5,5,5,5} =
  977728752/5$
- $\frac{a_5^{12}}{30} :[C_1^{15} C_2^{15} C_3^{15} C_4^{15}]
  \frac{1}{30} (C_1^5 +  C_2^5 +  C_3^5 + C_4^5)^{12}
  \\ = [C_1^{3} C_2^{3} C_3^{3} C_4^{3}]
  \frac{1}{30} (C_1 +  C_2 +  C_3 + C_4)^{12}
  \\ = \frac{1}{30} {12\choose 3,3,3,3} =
  12320$
- $\frac{a_{15}^{4}}{15} :[C_1^{15} C_2^{15} C_3^{15} C_4^{15}]
  \frac{1}{15} (C_1^{15} +  C_2^{15} +  C_3^{15} + C_4^{15})^{4}
  \\ = [C_1 C_2 C_3 C_4]
  \frac{1}{15} (C_1 +  C_2 +  C_3 + C_4)^{4}
  \\ = \frac{1}{15} {4\choose 1,1,1,1} = 8/5.$

The second term is special:

$$ \frac{a_1^2 a_2^{29}}{4} :[C_1^{15} C_2^{15} C_3^{15} C_4^{15}]
\frac{1}{4} (C_1 +  C_2 +  C_3 + C_4)^{2}
(C_1^2 +  C_2^2 +  C_3^2 + C_4^2)^{29}
= 0.$$

Adding all contributions we find

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
23713472717216429668046350036152.}$$

As for the  terms that do not contribute this  is decided by examining
powers.  E.g.   the term $\frac{1}{30} a_{10}^6$  yields $\frac{1}{30}
(C_1^{10} + C_2^{10} + C_3^{10} + C_4^{10})^{6}$ (tenth powers) and as
ten  does not  divide fifteen  we cannot  possibly obtain  the desired
distribution of colors, for a contribution of zero.